# Can't set an array to stack view

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble using an array of `UIButtons`.

I have an `HomeViewController` in my application, in the `HomeViewController` I have few `UICollectionViewCells`, when a user taps on a cell (aka `Product`) I want to move him to the `ProductDetailViewController`.

a `Product` is a `struct` that has few properties like color, name and `size` which is an `array of int`.

on the ProductDetailViewController I want to create a `product` and set the `ProductDetailView` views (like the UILabels for names, etc) accordingly.

One important thing I want to set is an array of `UIButtons` This array will be used as the `arrangedSubviews` of a `UIStackView`.

I made a variable called `QuantityButtons`, I made a `ProductDetailViewModel` which creates an `array of UIButtons` from the `array of int` and on my `ProductDetailView` file I have a viewModel variable that gets the viewModel I created with the data.

From it's `didSet` I try to set the array. The problem is, I always get nil and crash. My guess it happens because the `init()` happens before the `didSet` I crash and can't use this, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

A product may have a change in the quantities so I can't just use default values.

This is my ProductDetailViewModel:

```
struct ProductDetailViewModel {
var uid: String?
var productName: String?
var productManufacturer: String?
var image: String?
var quantityOptions: [UIButton]?
var storeName: String?
var storeID: String?
//TODO: Maybe add reviews...

init(product: Product) {
    self.uid = product.uid
    self.productName = product.productName
    self.productManufacturer = product.productManufacturer
    self.image = product.productImage
    self.quantityOptions = convertQuantityIntToButtons(product.quantity)
    self.storeName = product.storeName
    self.storeID = product.storeID
}

//Converting the quantity int array we got from the product to uibutton array with tag and title of the quntity.
//Example: We got in product.quantity the array [10, 20, 30] we will create an array of three UIButton, button one will have tag = 10, and title = "10" etc..
private func convertQuantityIntToButtons(_ quantities: [Int]) -> [UIButton] {
    var buttons: [UIButton] = []
    for q in quantities {
        let b = UIButton(type: .custom)
        b.tag = q
        b.setTitle(String(q), for: .normal)
        buttons.append(b)
    }

    return buttons
  }
}
```

This is my ProductDetailViewController:

```
class ProductDetailVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Properties
private let productDetailView = ProductDetailView()
private var selectedQuantity: Int?

private let demoProduct = Product(uid: "00000", productName: "PRODUCT NAME", productManufacturer: "PRODUCT MANUFACTURER", productImage: "PRODUCT IMAGE", quantity: [1, 2, 3, 4], amount: 1, notes: "PRODUCT NOTES", storeID: "123456", storeName: "STORE NAME", ownerID: "OWNER ID", SKU: "PRODUCT SKU")

//MARK: - Initializers
override func loadView() {
    self.view = productDetailView
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //productDetailView.delegate = self
    setProductDetails(product: demoProduct)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    productDetailView.animateBackButton()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }, completion: nil)
}

//Settings the product information we got in the view.
private func setProductDetails(product: Product) {
    productDetailView.productViewModel = ProductDetailViewModel(product: demoProduct)
}
}
```

This is my ProductDetailView:

```
class ProductDetailView: UIView {

var productViewModel: ProductDetailViewModel? {
    didSet {
        self.quantityButtons = productViewModel?.quantityOptions ?? []
        self.storeName.text = productViewModel?.storeName
        self.productName.text = productViewModel?.productName
        self.productManufacturerName.text = productViewModel?.productManufacturer
    }
}


//MARK: - Properties
var delegate: ProductDetailDelegate?
var quantityButtons: [UIButton] = [] //TODO: This should be a custom button.
private let imageContainerSize: CGFloat = 150

private lazy var quantitiesStack: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: self.quantityButtons) <---Crash here --------
    print(self.quantityButtons.count)
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.spacing = 2.0

    return stack
}()
}
```

Comment: Instead of declaring `quantitiesStack` as `lazy var`, what if you just did a `didSet` in your `quantityButtons` declaration that did everything there instead? Instead of returning stack, you would set quantitiesStack to `stack` in your `quantityButtons` `didSet`. This way you can guarantee that quantityButtons is not null since it will always set it to have contents when `didSet` is called there. You can even add a count check condition that only sets the stack view only if `quantityButtons.count > 0`

Comment: Thanks, but is it good practice though?

Comment: That's an opinionated question. I'm not sure whether it is bad practice, but I personally can't see why it would. What would make you think that it is?

Comment: It looks weird to me to create the StackView inside the didSet. Anyhow, The issue is resolved, I created an empty UIStackView and on the quantityButtons didSet I appended the buttons to it.